# Gmail SMTP timeout sending mail with Go net/smtp

Tags: go, smtp

I'm trying to use gmail SMTP relay to send email with go `net/smtp` from a docker container. I keep getting this error `dial tcp 142.251.12.108:587: connect: connection timed out`.

I have enabled 2-step verification and set an app password and required TLS. I tried using the IP of my server but that didn't work either, whether TLS is required or not. The user is the only user in the Google Workspace account.

None of the suggested questions contains any solution that explains why my code isn't establishing a TLS connection or how to fix it. One suggested solution is Java which I don't understand and another suggests using "less secure" connections which is isn't available as an option anymore. I have spent many hours searching for a solution to this issue without success. The net/smtp package is apparently supposed to establish a TLS connection so I have no idea why it doesn't. I disagree with the assertion that programming language does not matter. Every package contains functions which differ in implementation somewhat. The solution must be a go code solution.

Here is my code

```
authName := "mark@example.com"

password := "secret"

from := "mark@example.com"

host := "smtp.gmail.com"

port := "587"

body := []byte(message)

auth := smtp.PlainAuth("", authName, password, host)

toList = append(toList, "sombody@somedomain.com")

err = smtp.SendMail(host+":"+port, auth, from, toList, body)
```

edit: The issue turned out to be that Linode block common SMTP ports by default. If you hit this error on a Linode, raise a ticket to explain why you need to send emails and what you will do to prevent spam. They will likely then lift the restriction.

Comment: Connection timeout means that it is not able to establish a TCP connection to the given host and port. Any TLS or authentication comes afterwards, so setting are irrelevant for this error. Also programming language does not matter. Does this answer your question? [Application not able to connect to smtp host and port 587 using docker](/questions/59317586/), [Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 587; nested exception is: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect](/questions/38608089/).

Comment: No, the question does not propose a fix for my code. My understanding is that the client is meant to establish a TLS connection. The most recent answer contains a solution which is no longer available.

Comment: There is no fix for your code since the problem is outside of your code, i.e. missing connectivity to the SMTP server from inside the docker container. *"One suggested solution is Java"* - it's not: while the problem was in Java the solution was outside of it, i.e. make sure that there is connectivity.

Comment: DNS resolution worked. Another container in the same network on the same server connects to this API using a public domain. The container is able to pull its image so I doubt that connectivity is the issue.

Comment: *"Another container in the same network on the same server connects to this API using a public domain. "* - then check if your code is able to run in this container. *"The container is able to pull its image"* - which is not done with SMTP, so one cannot derive from this that SMTP connectivity (which you need) is working. *"DNS resolution worked."* - yes, otherwise the error would be different. Connectivity to the specific IP address and port does not work.